# How can I store sockets in a database?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to store sockets in my database and retrieve them also. But sockets are not serializable so I was unable to do this.

How can I store sockets in a database?

Comment: To the down voters - because someone doesn't know something you do, doesn't make this a bad question.  Consider that when down voting please!

Answer (score 18):

What about the socket do you wish to store in the database?  A socket itself represents something that cannot be stored in the databsae, but perhaps you can fetch the important attributes of a socket -- endpoints IP addresses, ports, and maybe some other important attributes if any -- and store those in the database as a proxy for the socket itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about what you *really* need to store in the database that represents the "conversation" with the client in your particular application.

For example, it could be a (securely generated) random number/session ID allocated on the server and which the client passes up as a cookie. It *might* be an IP address/remote port, bearing in mind that they should be regarded as temporary.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to store a socket in a database? Do you mean a data structure?

If it is a data structure you mean, then you could just store the sockets in a vector.

#### Example:

```
Vector yourNewPlaceToStoreSockets = new Vector();
yourNewPlaceToStoreSockets.add(yourSocketObject);
```

If you could be a bit more descriptive it would help me answer you better.

Comment: this is a random example, It was the best answer i could take for a question such as the one you gave

Comment: Please consider using a generic collection, i.e. Vector<Socket>. If you don't need a synchronised collection, you might be better off using an ArrayList<Socket>.

Answer (score 0):

A socket that your program has access to is a transient entity that will be relinquished. What do you mean by storing it in the databaqse? What are you trying to do?

Do you actually mean a database (like an external database management system) or a data structure? Because you could place it in a collection.